# How to switch on developer mode in iPhone 16 if I don't have access to macbook

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Team,

I am required to use developer mode on my iPhone 16, and all the articles suggest that I need Macbook to unlock developer mode using Xcode. But I do not have access to macbook. Is there no other way I can do it just by iPhone itself. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you install a build that requires developer mode then you will get the menu option in settings to enable it

Comment: Hi @Paulw11
In my understanding this was only possible in iOS 14 or below. Even after installing the build, I don't see developer option in iOS 16

Comment: There was no need to enable developer mode prior to iOS 16.  What happens when you try and run the build that needs developer mode?  Does that build include your phone's UDID?

Comment: Why do you need developer mode if you aren't using Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

1. Free version of [iMyFone AnyTo](https://www.imyfone.com/change-location/untrusted-enterprise-developer-ios-16/) can do it even on Windows. Just connect device to PC (you need iTunes installed) and open AnyTo - it will unhide developer mode in settings and guide your next steps.
2. Also free [iCareFone](https://www.tenorshare.com/ios-16/ios-16-developer-mode-not-showing.html) can do the same. After the device is connected open the program, click on the edit button (represented by a pen icon) next to the Quick Access section on the home page. Then, add developer mode tool to the quick access section to use.
3. If you don't have a PC nearby, you can try to sideload [supervise.me Developer Mode Enabler ipa](https://supervise.me/developermode) (via tools like AltStore) to unhide developer mode.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34668160)